# Batch file Pop up menu

Tags: batch-file, authentication, popup

Hello i would like to know if there is anyway that i can create a simple pop up login input for my Chat program.Here is the code for the login part:

```
    @echo off

    :home

    set ch==1
    color 0b
    title Logon Screen
    cls
    echo        Chat Login
    echo ___________________________
    echo 1.Logon
    echo.
    echo 2.Create an Account
    echo.
    echo 3.Exit
    echo ___________________________
    echo.
    set /p ch=Choice Number:
    if %ch%==1 goto logon
    if %ch%==2 goto account
    if %ch%==3 goto exit
    color 0c
    echo Please enter a valid number
    ping localhost -n 2 >nul
    goto home
```

Comment: Do you mean a popup box to replace `set /p ch=Choice Number:` or one for after `:login`? Wouldn't it just be easier to stick with `set /p`?

Comment: Why must it be a popop? Your batch can prompt for the value directly within the current window using SET /P.

Comment: @TheDarkTurtle I mean a pop up to replace set /p ch=Choice number: it sure would be easier to stick with set /p but I prefer a pop up it makes things a lot better looking...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a popup box for an input there are two basic ways of setting it up, one produces a javascript popup box and the other a second command window.

For the javascript popup box you should call [`rhino`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) which is an implementation of Javascript. Once you've downloaded it you'll be able to call it from `cmd`, as you would Python. You can [write the javascript for a popup box](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp) in a seperate file and then call it.

```
$ rhino file.js
```

The second way is calling a second batch file, using [`start`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true):

```
start file.bat
```

which would contain an input, for example

```
set /p username=Login:
```

Either will work, it just depends on what style you would like.

Comment: Fine, either method prompts for a value. But your parent batch never sees the value. You need a method to pass the input value back to the parent batch. Either write the value to a file and read the file in batch with SET /P or FOR /F, or else write the value to stdout, and parse the output with FOR /F.

Comment: I think il go with the    start     as I don't want to get in to java and make things complicated ..But the only thing is that I hate the style in    cmd    as u cannot change the font unless you do it manually and also the style and etc..

Comment: @Batchmage did it work? (_If_ it did, you should tell to me by 'ticking' the answer i.e. accepting it.) Yes, unfortunately that is true in Batch, but you'd need to use JavaScript or VB for a better looking box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if "%1"==":home" goto :home

  set r=r%random%
  set ch=1
  start /wait cmd /c "%~f0" :home

:ugly loop start
For /f "tokens=2,13 delims=, " %%a in (
    'tasklist /v /fo csv /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe"
    ^|findstr /v "Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"
    ^|findstr "set /p=%r%"'
     ) do (
        set pid=%%a
        set ch=%%b
        set ch=!ch:%r%=!
        set ch=!ch:~,-2!
        )
>nul 2>&1 taskkill /pid %pid:"=%
:ugly loop end

 if %ch%==1 goto logon
 if %ch%==2 goto account
 if %ch%==3 goto exit

exit /b

:logon
echo logon &pause&exit/b
:account
echo account &pause&exit/b
:exit
echo exit &pause&exit/b

    :home    
    color 0b
    title Logon Screen
    mode con lines=15 cols=27
    cls
    echo        Chat Login
    echo ___________________________
    echo 1.Logon
    echo.
    echo 2.Create an Account
    echo.
    echo 3.Exit
    echo ___________________________
    echo.
    set /p ch=Choice Number: 
    set ch=!ch:"=!
    if not "%ch%"=="1" if not "%ch%"=="2" if not "%ch%"=="3" (
    color 0c
    echo Please enter a valid number
    ping localhost -n 2 >nul
    goto home
    ) 
    start /min cmd /k mode con lines=1 cols=14 ^&set/p %r%!ch!=
```

OR:
change the last line to

```
            `exit/b !ch!`<br>
```

and instead of the **:ugly loop** label insert this:

```
            `set ch=%errorlevel%`
```

This makes so much simpler!